# Make an object's property display as color in the terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to do this? I wanted to use the npm module chalk and color a property so that when I JSON.stringify it and display the object contents in the terminal the property values will display as a color of my choosing so that its easier to read.

I was thinking something like:

```
const arrObjects = [
  {
    color: 'red',
    fruit: 'apple'
  },
  {
    color: 'pink',
    fruit: 'dragonfruit'
  }
];

const coloredProps = arrObjects.map(fruit => {
  Object.defineProperty(fruit, chalk.yellow.bold('family'), {
    value: 'healthy',
    writeable: true,
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: true
  });
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(arrObjects, null, 2));
```

So it would display the new property **family** in yellow

Which almost seems like I was getting there but the problem is that in the terminal it displays the property as a unicode because of the JSON.stringify. Is there a way to get passed this?

here is my result:

[image]

Comment: probably have to split all the lines, log each line separately and parse for property value to determine if it needs color or not

Answer (score 1):

Don't put ANSI escapes in your objects' values or keys. That's mixing display and data, which is only going to cause you problems.

JSON encoders usually escape non-printable or UTF-8 characters using their `\uXXXX` representations, which aren't recognized by terminal emulators (you need the *actual* character represented by `\x1b` or `\u001b`, not the escaped representation).

What your code is doing is essentially printing out `console.log('\\u001b')` - notice the double slash. Terminal emulators don't recognize that.

---

Have you tried the following?

```
var util = require('util');
console.log(util.inspect(myObject, {colors:true}));
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I'm a maintainer of the Chalk projects.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried strip-ansi utility for chalk

https://github.com/chalk/strip-ansi